# A pest is one who pesters

Tags: verbs

Normally when going from a verb to a person who performs that verb, one adds `er` to the verb. So, if you `walk` you are a `walker`; if you `deal` you are a `dealer`, and so on.

But I noticed recently that `pest` and `pester` are the wrong way round. If you `pester`, then you are a `pest`.

My question is: is this a one-off, or are there other verbs that share this phenomenon?

Comment: You are basing your question on a misapprehension: someone who pesters is a _pesterer_, not a pest. The verb is actually unrelated to the noun, except that the noun has influenced it to gain an _-st-_ cluster it did not originally have.

Comment: It's all so *vexing*.

Comment: Water the dog but don't milk the cat.

Comment: Apparently this question rests upon a misunderstanding about the etymological relationship between the words "pest" and "pester". While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one is unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by consulting good reference works before posting a question: in this case, a good dictionary or other source of etymology.

Comment: I think these closevotes are rather missing the point. Ugly nouns like ***pesterer*** and ***scamperer*** only "exist" because we don't like the implications of allowing the simpler forms to serve in the relevant context (i.e. - they seem to violate the common principle of normal "noun production" that goes from ***verb*** to ***verber***).

Answer (score 1):

[Etymologically speaking](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=scamp), it would appear that...

> *a **scamp** is one who **scampers***

I wouldn't like to say this is the only other example - in fact that seems vanishingly unlikely to me. It's just that I can't think of another one off the top of my head.

But obviously *in principle* there's no reason why the vagaries of language evolution shouldn't produce apparent "anomalies" like this. Just because there's a general rule applicable to many contexts doesn't mean that *all* words will undergo the same process.

Comment: Far less common, but apparently a ***flit*** could be seen as one who ***flitters***, and a ***glim*** is a light (such a candle) that ***glimmers***. And stretching a point, maybe a ***slob*** is one who ***slobbers***, a ***tot totters***, and a ***twit twitters***.